# How to replace Windows-style CR/LF line endings with Linux-style endings in ansible?

Tags: linux, sed, ansible

I tried this in my task, but doesn't seem to work

```
- name: Fix line endings from CRLF to LF
  local_action: replace dest={{my_dir}}/conf/{{item}} regexp='\r\n' replace='\n'
```

I usually do this using sed as follows and it works

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' file
```

I want to avoid using shell module to do this replacement as it throws a warning in ansible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible-vault errors with "Odd-length string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787412/ansible-vault-errors-with-odd-length-string)

Comment: not a duplicate, because the ansible-vault error is a result of having the wrong line-ending, not a means of changing it

Comment: Please mark a preferred answer if inclined :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the CRLF line endings with the `-replace` command. Your playbook might look like:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - local_action: replace dest={{my_dir}}/conf/{{item}} regexp="\r"
```

By not specifying the `replace` parameter in the `- replace` command, it will just remove all carriage returns. See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html.

I tested this with a local file I created and it worked when testing on localhost. It also worked when I added localhost to the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file and had the following playbook instead:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - replace: dest={{my_dir}}/conf/{{item}} regexp="\r"
```

Just be sure to use the absolute filepath.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
set_fact:
    my_content: "{{ lookup('file', "{{my_dir}}/conf/{{item}}" ) | replace('\r\n', '\n')}}"
```

After this you can use the content or save in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The following converts line endings using the Jinja2 template engine. A line-ending directive is inserted at the beginning of the source file on the ansible machine (`delegate_to: localhost`). Sending the file to the downstream server can then be done by applying `template` or `win_template` to the file.

It handles source files with any line-ending, which could be useful if you're working through a list of files from more than one origin.

```
- name: prepare to add line endings
  lineinfile:
    insertbefore: BOF
    dest: '{{ src_file }}'
    line: '#jinja2: newline_sequence:"\n"'
    #for Linux to Windows: #line: '#jinja2: newline_sequence:"\r\n"'
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: copy changed file with correct line-endings
  template: # win_template for Linux to Windows
    src: '{{ src_file }}'
    dest: '{{ dest_file }}'
```