# Hashicorp Vault roleid and secretid gives "unhexlify error: Odd-length string" when created as an ansible vault secret

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault, ansible-vault

I could see in the inventory roleid and secretid created as ansible vault secret so i can use it in my playbook.

```
secret_id:
  __ansible_vault: >
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    64306338633133643036396537306534393265626132616165326565656339313535393335326562
    **************
```

However when I use it in let say to see the value or use it in lookup task, it gives below error

```
{
    "msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ secret_id }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.parsing.vault.AnsibleVaultFormatError'>, original message: Vault format unhexlify error: Odd-length string",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

I also tried a working ansible vault secret which in debug runs but doesn't show any output which makes sense as you wouldn't want to easily visible in plaintext. But this secret_id fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible-vault errors with "Odd-length string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787412/ansible-vault-errors-with-odd-length-string)

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel I went through this post as well, it is not related as I am able to use other ansible vault encoded variables but not the roleid.

Comment: Then you will want to compose an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem using some sample data and a vault password of `password` because as it stands now, no one can _guess_ what's wrong with your setup